# How can you build such a full-text index that treats underscores as separate words in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

So that such queries would return a non-empty set:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+some +text' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

From a table where the only record's name attribute is 'some_text' . Basically I want to force InnoDB to treat underscores as delimeters when building the full-text index just like it does with dots and hyphens. How can this be achived natively in mysql or even with a 3rd party parser that has this by default?
Thank you

Edit: I'm aware that the easiest solultion would be to duplicate the column and separate the words there as I wish and build the index on that, but I'd rather not do that if not neccessary because the table has millions of rows..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the characters that define a word.  The place to look is in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) on fine-tuning the search.  Specifically, you want to control what characters are allowed in a word -- and you want `_` to be a non-word character.

One recommended method is to modify the character set file:

> Suppose that you want to treat the hyphen character ('-') as a word
>   character. Use one of these methods:
>
> . . .
>
> - Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish
>     letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents
>     of the  array in one of the character set XML files to
>     specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for
>     your FULLTEXT indexes. For information about the  array
>     format, see Section 10.3.1, “Character Definition Arrays”.

The only downside is that this will affect all full text indexes.

An alternative is to define a second column where you replace underscores with spaces and build the full text index on that.

If you want an index-specific approach, then another option is to define your own collation.

Note:  You may also need to be careful about the minimum word size.  The default is 3 or 4; smaller words are ignored.